# ESP8266 lags for some time and then updates very fast

Tags: java, android, arduino, wifi, esp8266

I have a problem with my connection between ESP and Android smartphone.

Every X time the ESP stops answering or sending anything on the serial port. Debugging on Android says "connection refused". Then, after 2-3min it starts spamming connection info to the serial port and after maybe 10s works normally.
I am also getting wifi evt: 7 - WIFI_EVENT_SOFTAPMODE_PROBEREQRECVED
According to https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2735
"[AP]err on recieved request"

...
New data every 300ms
...
Error:
19:48:58.765  wifi evt: 7
19:49:00.627  wifi evt: 7
19:49:00.627  wifi evt: 7
19:49:12.179  wifi evt: 7
...
Then updates very fast for a moment, about 50ms.

The ESP is in AP mode.

Newest libraries.

ESP code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//#include <Ticker.h>
//#include <Wire.h>
//#include "PCF8574.h"
//#include <ESP8266WiFiGratuitous.h>


const char* ssid = "wifitest2";
const char* password = "esp8266";
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);


WiFiServer server(80);
//Ticker timer;

const byte interruptPin = 13;
int czas2 = 0;
int czas = 0;
int a=1;
boolean auto_manual = 0;
unsigned long currentTime=0;
unsigned long previousTime=0;
const long Timeout=200;

//PCF8574 PCF_01(0x20);


void setup()
{
  delay(10);
  //pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), handleInterrupt, FALLING);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  //PCF_01.begin();

  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip,gateway,subnet);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password,10,true,1);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);

  server.begin();
  //experimental::ESP8266WiFiGratuitous::stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs();
  

  //timer.attach_ms(1,zegar);
}

// prepare a web page to be send to a client (web browser)
String prepareAnswer()
{
  String htmlPage;
  htmlPage.reserve(1024);               // prevent ram fragmentation
  htmlPage = F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
               "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
               "Connection: close\r\n"  // the connection will be closed after completion of the response
               "\r\n"
               "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
               "<html>");
  htmlPage += F("@"
              "300"
              "#" 
              "200"
              "$");
  htmlPage += F("</html>"
                "\r\n");
  return htmlPage;
}



void loop()
{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  // wait for a client (web browser) to connect
  if (client)
  {
    Serial.println("\n[Client connected]");
    while (client.connected())
    {
      yield();
      // read line by line what the client (web browser) is requesting
      if (client.available())
      {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        Serial.print(line);
        // wait for end of client's request, that is marked with an empty line
        if (line.length() == 1 && line[0] == '\n')
        {
          client.println(prepareAnswer());
          break;
        }
      }
      
    }

    while (client.available()) {
      
      // but first, let client finish its request
      // that's diplomatic compliance to protocols
      // (and otherwise some clients may complain, like curl)
      // (that is an example, prefer using a proper webserver library)
      client.read();
      yield();
    }

    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("[Client disconnected]");
  }
}
```

Android code:

```java
new HttpRequestAsyncTask(parameterValue, "192.168.0.1", "80", "").execute();
handler.postDelayed(this,300); //every XXX ms
  }
};
        
public String sendRequest(String parameterValue, String ipAddress, String portNumber, String parameterName) {
  String serverResponse = "ERROR";
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI website = new URI("http://" + ipAddress + ":" + portNumber + "/" + parameterName + parameterValue);
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
    getRequest.setURI(website);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest);
        
    InputStream content = null;
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    serverResponse = in.readLine();
    content.close();
  } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return serverResponse;
}
```

Comment: How is your Android device connected to the serial port of the ESP?

Comment: my huawei is connected by wifi to esp. I am reading serial port by arduino ide on pc

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with that sketch. The example (you must have followed) at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/esp8266wifi/server-examples.rst does get it right. Take it as a template and start making small changes - one at the time.

1. Your `Serial.println("[Client disconnected]");` is at the wrong place. It's inside the `if (client.available())` block but shouldn't.
2. You are missing the `client.stop()`.
3. You need to fully read the client request using `if (line.length() == 1 && line[0] == '\n')` or similar.
4. The concatenated response (using `s +=`) leads to heap fragmentation and produces invalid HTML code.

The only thing I would add to the example are `yield()` calls in each of the two `while`-loops. They help avoid starving system processes. The `WiFiServer` library might do that under the hood already but we can't be sure unless we check the code.

Comment: still the same problem, sometimes freeze for 1min, after that connecting and disconnecting very fast